# Adding Multiply Observers For NSNotificationCenter

Tags: ios, objective-c, refactoring

In my project, I am planning to use `NSNotificationCenter` for class-to-class communication. Therefore I am going to add a lot of observers in `NSNotificationCenter`. I am wondering if this is safe? or in other words, is this a good practice? Actually I am refactoring my code right now, and I want to sort out methods that shouldn't be done inside a class. As a matter of fact, I have a lot of alert controllers inside a `UIViewController` and it really bothers me every time I am debugging. Now, I just took out all those alert controllers and wrapped them in another class. For the callback block in `UIAlertAction` I am sending a notification to the `UIViewController`. Thats is why I am adding a lot of observers. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: You use the notification centre in the scenario where there is no one to one communication between the classes. Otherwise excessive use of notification centre is not a very good practice particularly when there are multiple observers of a single notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong, per se, with multiple observers for the same notification, or for a class to observe multiple notifications.

On the specific question of using notifications to pass information regarding UIAlertActions, don't do that.  There's nothing wrong with having a class that hides the boilerplate of creating specific UIAlertViewController instances with specific actions.  However, the API for such a class should have factory methods for each specific alert, and those methods should take blocks as parameters to represent the action handlers.  The bodies of the blocks would be defined in the UIViewController that invokes the alert.

**Example**

```
@interface CustomAlertsFactory : NSObject

+ (void)presentDeleteConfirmationAlertFromViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                                       withConfirmAction:(void (^)(UIAlertAction *action))confirmHandler
                                            cancelAction:(void (^)(UIAlertAction *action))cancelHandler;

@end
```

The implementation of that method would create a UIAlertViewController tailored as a delete confirmation.  The confirm and cancel actions would be configured to use the blocks passed as parameters.

On the view controller side, imagine you allow editing a table.  In `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` you would throw up the alert as follows:

```
[CustomAlertsFactory
 presentDeleteConfirmationAlertFromViewController:self
 withConfirmationAction:^(UIAlertAction *a) {
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
 }
 cancelAction:^(UIAlertAction *a) {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
 }
];
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. :) Before doing what I am doing right now, I also tried what you suggested. But can you give me just one reason why you think throwing notifications in this case is not advisable?

Comment: It's redundant.  You're only going to have one observer for each alert you display.  It decouples the display of the alert form the code which handles the actions.  It allows for bugs because observers have to unregister to avoid memory leaks.  It leaves you open for strange behavior/bugs if some previous observer never unregistered.

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much!